# How to make and use custom template-loader in Django

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to write a custom template loader in django which serves html templates which are present in a folder in my s3 bucket. Following is my custom_loader file

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.template import Origin, Engine
from django.template.loader import TemplateDoesNotExist
from django.template.loaders.base import Loader
from boto3.session import Session
from django.template import engines

ACCESS_KEY_NAME = getattr(settings, 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', getattr(settings, 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', None))
SECRET_KEY_NAME = getattr(settings, 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY', getattr(settings, 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY', None))
TEMPLATE_BUCKET = getattr(settings, 'AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')

django_engine = engines['django']
template = django_engine.from_string("Hello {{ name }}!")


class S3Engine(Engine):

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "s3_engine"

    def __str__(self):
        return "s3_engine"


class Loader(Loader):
    is_usable = True

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "loader"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        django_engine = engines['django']
        print(engines.all())
        template = django_engine.from_string("Hello {{ name }}!")
        print(template)
        params = args[0]
        print(args)
        print('params', params)
        session = Session(aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY_NAME,
                          aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY_NAME)
        s3 = session.resource('s3')
        self.bucket = s3.Bucket(TEMPLATE_BUCKET)
        super(Loader, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # self.engine = S3Engine(dirs=params['DIRS'], context_processors=options, loaders=Loader)


    def getKeys(self):
        keys_objects = []
        for obj in self.bucket.objects.filter(Prefix="media/festive_html/"):
            key = obj.key
            keys_objects.append({
                'key': key,
                'object': obj
            })
        return keys_objects

    def get_contents(self, origin):
        print(111111)
        print('origin', origin)
        try:
            keys_objects = self.getKeys()
            for key_object in keys_objects:
                print('origin', origin)
                print('key_object', key_object)
                if key_object['key'] == origin:
                    return key_object['object'].get()['Body'].read()
        except FileNotFoundError:
            raise TemplateDoesNotExist(origin)


    def get_template_sources(self, template_name, template_dirs=None):
        tried = []
        # print('template_name', template_name)
        # template_name = "media/" + template_name
        print(11111)
        yield Origin(
            name=template_name,
            template_name=template_name,
            loader=self,
        )
        print(333333)
        tried.append('/index.html')
        print(444444)
        if tried:
            print(555555555)
            error_msg = "Tried Keys %s" % tried
        else:
            print(6666666)
            error_msg = "Your TEMPLATE_DIRS setting is empty. Change it to point to at least one template directory."
        raise TemplateDoesNotExist(error_msg)

    get_template_sources.is_usable = True
```

and in my settings i have set the template settings in following way.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django',
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')],
        'APP_DIRS': False,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'loaders': [
                'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
                'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
                's3template_loader.Loader',
            ],
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

and following is my view

```
def generate_html(request, template_id)
    template_instance = TemplateData.objects.get(id=template_id) 
    html = template_instance.html
    rendered = render_to_string(html, response)
    return rendered
```

but when i am trying to access my end point i am getting the below error:

```
TypeError: 'Engine' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

PS: This question is similar to the below question with the difference that I don't want to use a different template Engine but just a different template loader that renders templates from s3.

[custom template loader Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54143892/custom-template-loader-django)

Comment: First question that springs to mind is, why? Static files from S3 make sense because they're served to the browser so the person viewing the site can see them. But template files are needed by the web server so that django can render them, so it makes sense to keep them on the server.

Comment: I want to upload various kinds of graphics like festive greetings in HTML format and users can customize it based on their needs by passing context and eventually download a PDF/PNG file by converting the HTML to PDF using wkhtmltopdf. I don't want to make changes in the code for every new graphic. I am uploading them from Django Admin Panel currently.